# Flattening embedded keys with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying (unsuccessfully) to create separate columns for embedded dictionary keys.  Dict data looks like this:

```
{'averagePrice': 32.95,
  'currentDayProfitLoss': 67.2,
  'currentDayProfitLossPercentage': 0.02,
  'instrument': {'assetType': 'EQUITY', 'cusip': '902104108', 'symbol': 'IIVI'},
  'longQuantity': 120.0,
  'marketValue': 4021.2,
  'settledLongQuantity': 120.0,
  'settledShortQuantity': 0.0,
  'shortQuantity': 0.0}]
```

The 'instrument' key is what I am trying to flatten in to columns (ie assetType, cusip, symbol).  Here is the code I last tried and still no indivdual columns

```
data = accounts_data_single
my_dict = data
headers = list(my_dict['securitiesAccount']['positions'])
dict1 = my_dict['securitiesAccount']['positions']


mypositions = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
pd.concat([mypositions.drop(['instrument'], axis=1), mypositions['instrument'].apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
mypositions.to_csv('Amer_temp.csv')
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated

I am trying to get the nestled keys/fieldnames all in columns and then all the stock positions in the rows.  The above code works great except the nestled 'instrument' keys are all in one column

```
averagePrice  currentDayProfitLoss  ...  assetType  cusip  symbol
22.5          500                   ...  Equity     013245  IIVI
450           250                   ...  Equity     321354  AAPL
etc
```

Comment: can you post expected output, i added an answer if IIUC but if that 's not what your looking for i'll delete it. example output would be great!

Comment: Yes and thank you very much , I am attempting to have all the keys in individual columns vs grouped in one under instrument.  Below is screenshot of csv created with 'instrument' column containing all nested keys but would like nested keys in separate columns.  guess cant paste screenshot sorry will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this:

```
pd.DataFrame(d).assign(**pd.DataFrame([x['instrument'] for x in d])).drop(columns='instrument')
```

output:

```
   averagePrice  currentDayProfitLoss  currentDayProfitLossPercentage  longQuantity  marketValue  settledLongQuantity  settledShortQuantity  shortQuantity assetType      cusip symbol
0         32.95                  67.2                            0.02         120.0       4021.2                120.0                   0.0            0.0    EQUITY  902104108   IIVI
1         31.95                  63.2                            0.01         100.0       3021.2                100.0                   0.0            0.0    EQUITY  802104108   AAPL
```

Comment: your solution worked perfect.  Thanks, Is there a way on stack overflow to give you rewards similar to reddit ?

Comment: @BruceHarrison I'm glad it worked, and yes! you can reward me by checking out this document: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235  Basically it rewards us both when you accept the answer

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do this. Let's say `d` is your dict.

**Step 1:** Convert the dict to dataframe

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').T.reset_index(drop=True)
```

**Step 2:** Convert the `instrument` column into dataframe

```
d2 = d1['instrument'].apply(pd.Series)
```

**Step3:** Join outputs of step1 and step2

```
df = pd.concat([d1.drop('instrument', axis=1), d2], axis=1)
```